# RecyclerView addInArray error when adding

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I add in `List<OrderList>` any item in `loadOrdersData()`, it throws this:

> D/ViewGroup: addInArray been called, this = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView {41cab8f0 VFED.... .F....ID 0,0-480,770 #7f0c0073 app:id/rv}call stack = java.lang.Throwable: addInArray at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3786) at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3740) at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3564) at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3509) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:649) at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7115) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7073) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7061) at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1428) at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377) at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315) at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3568) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862) at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1197) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862) at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:433) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862) at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888) at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742) at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560) at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I tried adding: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` before `setAdapter()` in `loadOrdersData()` but it makes no sense. Does anyone see what it is caused by?

Here's the code:

MainActivity:

```
public class CourierActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TableLayout orderTable;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecycleAdapter adapter;
    private List<OrderListItem> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.courier_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CourierActivity.this));
        adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        loadOrdersData();
    }

    private void loadOrdersData() {    
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                listItems = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    String rsp = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    JSONArray orders = new JSONArray(rsp);

                    for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
                        OrderListItem listItem = new OrderListItem(
                                // .. 
                        );

                        listItems.add(listItem);
                    }

                    adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(sr);
    }
}
```

OrderListItem:

```
public class OrderListItem {
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private String price;
    private String courier;

    public OrderListItem(String name, String status, String price, String courier) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.price = price;
        this.courier = courier;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public String getStatus() { return status;}

    public String getPrice() { return price; }

    public String getCourier() { return courier; }
}
```

RecycleAdapter:

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<OrderListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecycleAdapter(List<OrderListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        OrderListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.TextViewName.setText(listItem.getName());
        holder.TextViewStatus.setText(listItem.getStatus());
        holder.TextViewPrice.setText(listItem.getPrice());
        holder.TextViewCourier.setText(listItem.getCourier());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int count = 0;

        if (listItems != null && !listItems.isEmpty()) {
            count = listItems.size();
        }

        return count;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView TextViewName;
        public TextView TextViewStatus;
        public TextView TextViewPrice;
        public TextView TextViewCourier;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            TextViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderListName);
            TextViewStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderListStatus);
            TextViewPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderListPrice);
            TextViewCourier = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderListCourier);
        }
    }

}
```

@layout/rv_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orderListName"
                android:text="Order name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orderListStatus"
                android:text="Status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orderListPrice"
                android:text="Price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orderListCourier"
                android:text="Courier"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

@layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.seether.myapplication.CourierActivity"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"/>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**EDIT**. Works perfect without log's warnings if I enter custom data into `listItems`.

Comment: first thing i got to know that, you are passing "listItems" which is NULL, when you passed in Adapter on "onCreate()" method. Try to initialize it before sending it. THEN LET ME KNOW WHATS HAPPENING NOW

Comment: @ankitpatidar tried this, it makes no sense too :(

Comment: put your "OrderListItem" class in the question

Comment: Hey can you please give us url, by which we can check ? thanks

Comment: @ankitpatidar sorry it's a private url. you can check it just with a loop.

Comment: @phenOmen but without url, it doesnot go  into "onResponse()" method, and loop doesnt work there

Comment: hey its working correctly, surely there is problem in your webservice. CHeck my answer for screenshot

Comment: @ankitpatidar yeah its working correctly but take a look to logs

Comment: have a look at my answer

Comment: @phenOmen have a look at my code??? Working currectly. But can't able to check for we service

Comment: @ankitpatidar Man I said you to have a look to log. Application runs correctly but the error still appears in the logs. Every error should be fixed.

Comment: @phen0men, check my answer

Comment: ```adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext()); recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);``` Why do you reassign it? just use ```adapter.setList(listItems)```

Comment: @phen0men removing `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` will change the crash?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, CourierActivity.this);
```

instead of

```
adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
```

Also add orientation in your `RecyclerView`

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Update this:

```
 String rsp = new String(response.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Did you change in both sides?

Comment: yes, in `onCreate()` and `loadOrdersData()` methods

Comment: is the error after "loadOrdersData()" ? what happens if you comment that method ?

Comment: if I comment that method, nothing happens. So yes, this error appears after `loadOrdersData()`

Comment: add android:orientation="vertical" in your recyclerview

Comment: does it works if you use : String rsp = new String(response, "UTF-8"); ?

Comment: Adding vertical orientation didnt solve the problem. But `String rsp = new String(response, "UTF-8");` throws an error: `Cannot resolve constructor (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

Comment: Still doesn't work. `response.getBytes()` without parameter can't recognize cyrillic letters. The error still appears. I don't know what's wrong :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat, please](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160009/discussion-between-phen0men-and-diegoveloper).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

> CourierActivity.java

```
public class CourierActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
   //Don't forget to intialize your List
    private List<OrderListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<OrderListItem>();
    ...

    private void loadOrdersData() {    
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                listItems = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    String rsp = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    JSONArray orders = new JSONArray(rsp);

                    for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
                        OrderListItem listItem = new OrderListItem(
                                // .. 
                        );

                        listItems.add(listItem);
                    }
                    //set list to adapter this way
                    adapter.setList(listItems);
                } catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(sr);
    }
    }
```

> RecycleAdapter.java

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<OrderListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecycleAdapter(List<OrderListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public setList(List<OrderListItem> listItems){
        //add list to parent list and notify your adapter
        this.listItems.addAll(listItems);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    ...
}
```

**Edit 1 :**

> main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.seether.myapplication.CourierActivity"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"/
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @phen0men, I have updated my ans, please make your `main.xml` like this

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have main `DrawerLayout` in main.xml for NavigationDrawer. But I tried to remove and replace it to your code. Problem still remains.

Comment: I don't think it's because of this, I have done similar thing so many times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160281/discussion-between-maddy-and-phen0men).

Answer (score 1):

I have made couple of changes and written in comment. Try that out,

```
public class CourierActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TableLayout orderTable;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecycleAdapter adapter;

    //********* Initialize over here **********//
    private List<OrderListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.courier_main);

        //********** Initialize *******//
        mContext = CourierActivity.this;

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CourierActivity.this));

        //********* added class context *********//
        adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, mContext);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        loadOrdersData();
    }

    private void loadOrdersData() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //******** Remove this line *************//
                listItems = new ArrayList<>();

                //******** Add this line ************//
                listItems.clear();

                try {
                    String rsp = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    JSONArray orders = new JSONArray(rsp);

                    for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
                        OrderListItem listItem = new OrderListItem(
                                // ..
                        );

                        listItems.add(listItem);
                    }



                    //*********Remove these both lines **********//
                    adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    //************ Add this line **********//
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(sr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your modifications don't add `listItems` in `recycleView`.

Comment: I have already added listItems while creating adapter object. When you get response then you fill up the listItem. You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() of adapter and it will automatically refresh the recycleview @phen0men

Comment: Have you integrated my changes ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's still throwing the logs. App works perfect but I am afraid because of these logs.

Answer (score 1):

Volley seems to get the data asynchronously, so the most reasonable way to manage the `RecyclerView` is setting the adapter at first with an empty (but not null) `List` and the **Activity** context (e.g. `Mainactivity.this`).

When Volley has finally got all the elements, you add all of them (instead of `for(int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++)` you could use `for(OrderListItem listItem : orders);`), you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: where do I call the last method?

Comment: Just call it after `setAdapter` in your onCreate() but do not call it again nor create a new instance of it inside the method.

Comment: still the same. I think the problem caused by the custom recycle adapter

Comment: Have you tried not to `addAll()` but to set the value (=)??

Comment: yeah, i have tried it. this way doesnt solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of create new `ArrayList` and `RecyclerAdapter` instance in `onResponse()`, I prefer,

1. Clear `listItems`.
2. Add all `OrderListItem` instance to `listItems`.
3. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of `adapter`.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
     listItems.clear();

     try {
         //loop and add all items to listItems here
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     } catch (JSONException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

and make sure that you initialize `RecyclerAdapter` properly because I do not see any code that create `listItems` in `onCreate()` method of `CourierActivity`.

```
 listItems = new ArrayList<OrderListItem>();
 adapter = new RecycleAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the **list** object from activity to adapter. Instead have a separate array list in adapter. 
Change your adapter constructor to this:

```
     public RecycleAdapter(List<OrderListItem> listItems, Context context) {
         this.listItems = new ArrayList<>(listItems);
         this.context = context;
    }
```

And as Maddy suggested use a setMethod in adapter passing the listitem array and adding all items to it and calling notifyDataSetChanged.

I guess this should solve your problem when you don't use the same listitems object in activity and adapter.

Comment: Well.. Problem still remains. The app works perfect, `recycleView` has its updates by **[this](https://pastebin.com/8mQqHV08)** method in `RecycleAdapter`. But in the RUN logs, when I add/update the `listItems` in `RecycleAdapter`, app throws too many logs (3 items in `listItems` = 3 logs): **https://pastebin.com/1TGxC4HJ** Maybe it isn't an error but just a log?